# How do I mute the guitar in a song so I can play with the backing track?

Tags: guitar, software

I am tired of Karaoke style backing tracks and want to replace the guitar in a song that I already have. Can I do this with software?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the song, search the web for MIDI files. Under success, you can open MIDI file with some even free tool like MuseScore and [remove](http://musescore.org/node/11198) unwanted staffs. The rest can be played by MuseScore directly or you can also export and burn CD.

Answer (score 0):

There have been many sites which claim to "phase out" the instrument, but there are always those transients in the background like cymbals still lingering around.
[Jammit](http://www.jammit.com) has licensed the original backing tracks from the labels so you can mute or isolate the part you want to learn. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I have been seeing a lot of adverts on YouTube recently for a piece of software called [RiffStation](http://www.riffstation.com/). It's supposedly able to isolate (and in your case mute) the guitar on tracks. I haven't had a chance to try it out yet, but the video demos look very interesting indeed.

[YouTube Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdRoHAGCnUY)